# Can we use self-signed certification for our azure function which run on timer schedule/trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, self-signed-certificate

I developed an Azure Function which is timer triggered. For this I created a self-signed certification :

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -dnsname "SP Az Func 3"
$pwd =ConvertT-SecureString -String "**************" -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -cert cert:\localMachine\my\EB7D9E53BA1DF88AEDE1EA8CA3488CD794E0A9E9 -FilePath "c:\SPAzFunc2.pfx" -Password $pwd
Export-Certificate -cert cert:\localMachine\my\EB7D9E53BA1DF88AEDE1EA8CA3488CD794E0A9E9 -FilePath "c:\SPAzFunc2.crt"
```

Can I use this self-sign certificate to run our azure function on production? If not, then how we can gain/buy `.pfx` and `.crt` from authorized resources and provide a password, as we do in the self-signed certificate?
Thanks

Comment: Since you're using this on a timer trigger function I presume this certificate is not for SSL/TLS binding. So what do you intend to use the certificate for?

Comment: @ma499 it is part of authenticating my Azure function to SharePoint Online, previous we use to pass the ClientID & ClientSecret. now for modern authentication we pass the CertificateThumbPrint, TenantId & ClientId as mentioned on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9erhWdwbkq8

Answer (score 1):

The youtube video you mentioned already describes HOW you can use a certificate with Azure Functions. For others, the most important part is also documented as "[Use a TLS/SSL certificate in your code in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code)".

So your actual question is "Can I use self-signed certificates for AAD application authentication **in production**?".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-self-signed-certificate

> For testing, you can use a self-signed public certificate instead of a Certificate Authority (CA)-signed certificate. In this how-to, you'll use Windows PowerShell to create and export a self-signed certificate.
>
> Self-signed certificates are not trusted by default and they can be difficult to maintain. Also, they may use outdated hash and cipher suites that may not be strong. For better security, purchase a certificate signed by a well-known certificate authority.

It is definitely technically possible to use self-signed certificates in production. It might also be fine for your use case. However, it depends on your level of confidence that the solution is sufficient for your use case (business requirements etc.). Nobody is going to give you a blank recommendation except "when in doubt - buy a certificate".

Anything further and especially "how do I buy a client certificate?" does not belong on StackOverflow. Maybe you could ask this question on ServerFault - or rather use the search function there first.